# Mock object under mocked object

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to mock the instance of a mocked object. I tried, but the object in coming as null.

Basically I need to try to call the real implementation as much as possible, the second level of mocking is not happening.

Any idea guys, how to do it.

```
public class mytest{

@Mock
Myutil myutil;

@InjectMock
ClassunderTest ct

  @Before
  setup()
  {
  MockitoAnotation.initMocks(ct);
  }

  @Test
  test1(){
    when(myutil.dotask()).thenReturn("");
    ct.m1();
  }
}

public class ClassunderTest{
@inject
MyUtil u1;
  public string m1(){
    u1.dotask();
  }
}

public class MyUtil(){
@inject
mockunderMock needtomock; //this instance needs to be mocked
  public dotask(){
      needtomock.play()
   }
}
```

Comment: If you mock `mockunderMock`, then supposedly you will also have to mock response of `needtomock.play()`. Can you acheive same thing by mocking `myutil.dotask()` ?

Answer (score 0):

A mock is not a real object so it doesn't have a `needtomock` field. You probably want to use a programmed behavior here (`Mockito.when()` etc) or use a real `MyUtil` instance with a mocked `mockundertest`

Some reading: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Could you please give a small example,